# ggplot2 issue with plotting points and polygons

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a simple map using ggplot2 to display a series of river basins and data points.

The data points are stored in a .csv file and look like this:

[image: Points]

I've projected the points and created a SpatialPointDataFrame and then stored them in a dataframe:

```
points <- read.csv(c(paste0("./Points/", "points.csv")), header = T, sep = ",")
coordinates(points) <- ~Lat + Lon
cord <- "+init=epsg:2163"
proj4string(points) <- CRS(cord)
points_df <- as.data.frame(points, region = "id")
```

The basin files are all stored in the same directory and have been read into a single spatialpolygonsdataframe which looks like this:

[image: spatialpolygonsdataframe]

then are converted to a dataframe using this:

```
basins_TX$id <- rownames(basins@data)
basins_TX_df <- tidy(basins, region = "id")
```

Then I try to create a map using this code:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = basins_df, 
               aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), 
               fill = "white", color = "black") + 
  geom_point(data = points_df, 
             aes(x = Lon, y = Lat),
             color = "red")
```

this creates a map with polygons and one point at 0,0:

[image: plot]

This happens no matter what subsection of the data I am looking at. I want to accurately display the points and the polygons.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Without seeing the data, can't say. Maybe wrong projection, since the basin `Longs` are in the 1,000,000s.

Comment: I tried to update the question to include more information/a reproducible example. I did not know how to share a sample of the basin shapefiles. does this make any more sense?

Comment: I also think it is probably a projection issue, but both should be in the same projection. crs(points) returns: 
CRS arguments:
 +init=epsg:2163 +proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6370997 +b=6370997 +units=m +no_defs   Which matches the spatialpolygonsdataframe in the question

Comment: You may want to double-check the dataframes passed into `ggplot()` directly, rather than the original datasets' CRS. From the plot, `basins_df`'s lat & lon values are clearly much larger. Perhaps the issue arose at the conversion to data frame step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in fact related to the projection of my data. I had defined the projection of the points file rather than projecting it, so it was incorrect. I was able to correct this by redefining it correctly and the projecting the points file using `spTransform`

leaving this up in case other run into similar issues, although the error was not in the ggplot2 script.